# Python Tkinter input date subtraction

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter

I've been trying to get my Tkinter dialog to do a simple date subtraction, but something is holding it up. The date subtraction seems to hold up when run from the shell, but I'm getting nothing from this is Tk.

The code is borrowed from another script that I have running successfully with all the form and windows setup.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *
import datetime
import math

fields = ('Enter Date (mm/dd/yy)', 'Days Since 10/30/14')

def Calc(entries):
   d = raw_input(entries['Enter Date (mm/dd/yy)'].get())
   nd = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%y").date()
   d1 = "10/30/14"
   od = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, "%m/%d/%y").date()
   diff = (nd - od).days
   diff = ('%8.2f' % diff).strip()
   entries['Days Since 10/30/14'].delete(0,END)
   entries['Days Since 10/30/14'].insert(0, diff)

def makeform(root, fields):
   root.title('Date Difference')
   entries = {}
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=22, text=field+": ", anchor='w', font=('arial', 12))
      ent = Entry(row, font=('arial', 12))
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries[field] = ent
   return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   root.geometry("400x400+300+300")
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: Calc(e)))
   b1 = Button(root, text='Calculate', font=('arial',12), command=(lambda e=ents: Calc(e)))
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text='Quit', font=('arial',12), command=root.quit)
   b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Even now I messed it up more, somehow it doesn't even start at all and highlights the "lab" variable under `makeform(root,fields):` it was running a minute ago, though would not do the calculation...

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = raw_input(entries['Enter Date (mm/dd/yy)'].get())
```

`raw_input` gets data from the user via the command line. Is that intentional? You don't need it if you just want to find what the user typed into the entry.

```
d = entries['Enter Date (mm/dd/yy)'].get()
```

Comment: Thanks! Yep, well first, I was missing the ")" at the end of the line before the "lab" variable in my version here, that's why it stopped working altogether. But after replacing that and removing raw_input it worked fine. I guess I thought I needed it because I had used float before for number entries and for some reason raw_input seemed like a way to go for non-numerical stuff. Thanks again, now I'm going to try to add more functions to this...